# How to remove duplicate rows and keep one in an Access database based on the larger ID number?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, duplicates, ms-access-2016

I have a 60K+ row table in MS Access. I would like to check for duplicate rows and delete them from my table. A duplicate row would have the same [Mfg part number] AND [Manufacturer] AND [Substitution]. I also have a primary key field called "ID". I would like to keep the duplicate row with the larger ID number. I have created an "IsDeleted" column to help faciliate but can't figure out how to change the duplicate rows I want to delete to have a 1 in the IsDeleted column.

| ID | Mfg part number | Manufacturer | Substitution | IsDeleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC123 | Peter | ABC098 | 0 |
| 2 | ABC123 | Peter | ABC098 | 0 |
| 3 | ABC123 | Peter | XYZ123 | 0 |
| 4 | JKLMNOP | Smith | WERTR | 0 |
| 5 | JKLMNOP | Jane | WTTTTR | 0 |
| 6 | JKLMNOP | Jane | WTTTTR | 0 |
| 7 | THING1 | Carter | WIDGET1 | 0 |
| 8 | THING2 | Carter | WIDGET2 | 0 |

So, in this example, ID 1 and 2 are duplicate rows because Mfg part number, manufacturer and substitution are all equal. How would I keep on the larger row ID = 2 and delete row ID = 1. Also, row ID = 3 is not a duplicate because there is a different Substitution. Row ID 5 and 6 are duplicates too.

Thank for any help!!

```
UPDATE tblCrossReferences
SET IsDeleted = 1
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT tblCrossReferences.IsDeleted, tblCrossReferences.ID, tblCrossReferences.[Mfg part number], tblCrossReferences.Manufacturer, tblCrossReferences.[Substitution], MAX(tblCrossReferences.ID)
FROM tblCrossReferences
WHERE (((tblCrossReferences.[Mfg part number]) In (SELECT [Mfg part number] FROM [tblCrossReferences] As Tmp GROUP BY [Mfg part number],[Manufacturer],[Substitution],[SKF Alternative Offer] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [Manufacturer] = [tblCrossReferences].[Manufacturer] And [Substitution] = [tblCrossReferences].[Substitution])))
ORDER BY tblCrossReferences.[Mfg part number], tblCrossReferences.Manufacturer, tblCrossReferences.[Substitution]);
```

Comment: Try: `DELETE * FROM table WHERE NOT ID IN (SELECT MID FROM (SELECT [Mfg Part Number], Manufacturer, Substitution, Max(ID) AS MID FROM table GROUP BY [Mfg Part Number], Manufacturer, Substitution))`. But why delete data instead of just filtering?

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```sql
Delete * 
From tblCrossReferences
Where ID Not In
    (Select Top 1 ID 
    From tblCrossReferences As T
    Where 
        T.[Mfg part number] = tblCrossReferences.[Mfg part number] And
        T.Manufacturer = tblCrossReferences.Manufacturer And
        T.Substitution = tblCrossReferences.Substitution
    Order By ID Desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all versed in MS Access, but in SQL you would typicall use `EXISTS` for such a task, i.e. delete all rows for which exists a better row.

```
UPDATE tblCrossReferences
SET IsDeleted = 1
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM tblCrossReferences AS better
  WHERE better.[Mfg part number] = tblCrossReferences.[Mfg part number]
    AND better.[Manufacturer]    = tblCrossReferences.[Manufacturer]
    AND better.[Substitution]    = tblCrossReferences.[Substitution]
    AND better.id                > tblCrossReferences.id
);
```

Same with a physical delete instead of a logical one:

```
DELETE FROM tblCrossReferences
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM tblCrossReferences AS better
  WHERE better.[Mfg part number] = tblCrossReferences.[Mfg part number]
    AND better.[Manufacturer]    = tblCrossReferences.[Manufacturer]
    AND better.[Substitution]    = tblCrossReferences.[Substitution]
    AND better.id                > tblCrossReferences.id
);
```